# Redirect to specific page according to the browser

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect

Hello guys I want my page to redirect to say "GOOGLE" when it is opened in Chrome browser and say "YOUTUBE" when opened in firefox.

I've tried to detect the user's browser through the `navigator.appCodeName` which returns the browser name but it is not working it is woking only in mozilla.
    `<body onload="myFunction()">`
    `<script>
     function myFunction() {
       var x = navigator.appCodeName;
    if(x.indexOf('Chrome')>=0){
    window.location.href="http://youtube.com";
     }else{
    window.location.href="http://google.com";
    }
}`
      
Can any one please help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

- use window.location.replace("---url here---")
- All modern browsers returns "Mozilla",for compatibility reasons.
- So Iam using here `navigator.userAgent` Returns the user-agent header sent by the browser to the server.
- and It returns `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0` if it is mozilla
- `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36` if it is chrome.

  `<body onload="myFunction()">
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
  var x = navigator.userAgent;
  if(x.indexOf('Chrome')>=0){
  window.location.replace("https://google.com")
  console.log("hello chrome");
  }else{
  window.location.replace("https://youtube.com");
  console.log("hello mozilla");
  }
   }`

  Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you that was correct but whats wrong in using href.?